# using const variable in array throws error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const a = 'aaaa'
const b = 'bbbb'

[a, b].forEach(s => console.log(s))
```

this throws cannot access to 'b' before initialization

I will appreciate help from community

I was expecting console log like 'aaaa' and 'bbbb'

Comment: You omitted the semicolon after `'bbbb'`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion